# Pass image picked from gallery to other intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, image-gallery, bitmapimage

I want to pass image picked from gallery to other intent. But when I click upload button and then select image from gallery it shows me the same activity. As if i am stuck on  that activity. Can anyone help?????
This is my code..

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    Uri photouri = data.getData();

    if (photouri != null) {
        try {
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photouri,
                    filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int ColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String FilePath = cursor.getString(ColIndex);
            cursor.close();

            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FilePath);


            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
            intent2.putExtra("BitmapImage", photo);
            startActivity(intent2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Code in Activity2

```
pic1= (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
img.setImageBitmap(pic1);
```

Comment: check whether data.getData() return null or what . and please pass uri to another activity instead of passing bitmap to the putExtra and in other activity use asynctask to convert it into bitmap and display in imageview.

Comment: and please try to put some debugging. put breakpoint or log for more info it will easily solve most of the problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this in my app but instead of calling decodeFile in first activity,
I just passed the actual filename (path) selected from the gallery and 
let the second activity decode it.

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
Activity2.intent2.putString("BitmapFilename",FilePath); 
startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: putString is showing some error.. i have tried putExtra. But it is still not working. When i select image from gallery, application is force closed.